# Creating html table with millions record using javascript blocking browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Please read my question complete before answer or marking it duplicate because i am dealing with constraint in my problem.**

Hi All Javascript rock stars,

I am creating a html table with javascript. In table i need scroller both vertical and horizontal. I am done with this part. It is working. Now my problem starts. When i am creating millions rows for the table it block my browser. For few thousand record it work fine.

I have done lot of google to improve performance but did not gain any significant performance improvement. Like some has suggested to use  row.appendChild(cell); I have also tried to use Workers. But then i found i can not have access of document object in Workers. setTimeout is also not sufficient to solve my problem. Here is my code for creating rows of table.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(rcvReq.responseText);
    var json = arr.abc;
    var columns = [];
    columns = Object.keys(json[0]);
     //Build an array containing Customer records.
    var customers = new Array();
    customers.push(columns);
    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { 
         var dataVal = [];
        for(j = 0; j < columns.length; j++){
             var mytempvar = json[i]; 
            dataVal.push(mytempvar[columns[j]+'']);
        }
        customers.push(dataVal);
    }
    //Create a HTML Table element.
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    var table1 = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.border = "1";
    //Get the count of columns.
    var columnCount = customers[0].length;
    //Add the header row.
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.className = 'fixed-header';
    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
        headerCell.innerHTML = customers[0][i];
        row.appendChild(headerCell);
    }
    table1.appendChild(row);
    //Add the data rows.
     var documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 1; i < customers.length; i++) {
        row = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            var cellVal = customers[i][j];
                var cell = document.createElement("TD");
                cell.innerHTML = cellVal;
                row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){ }, 1000);
        documentFragment.appendChild(row);
    }
     /* Event of button  */
    var siblings = e.parentNode.children;
    var childOf1stShibling = siblings[0];
    table.appendChild(documentFragment);
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    var dvTable = document.getElementById(siblings[1].id +'');
    var dvTable1 = document.getElementById(childOf1stShibling.children[0].id + '');
    dvTable.innerHTML = "";
    dvTable1.innerHTML = "";
    dvTable.appendChild(table);
    dvTable1.appendChild(table1);
```

**Constraint**

1. No use of jquery. Only i can use javascript, css and html.
2. No use of third party plugin.
3. I can not use pagination.
4. Records are in millions not in thousand.

Please suggest any workaround keeping above constraint in mind.
 Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use jquery? It ease your codes!

Comment: And how would you expect anyone who can view millions of table rows on the web? It is a poor idea.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I have already mention i have this constraint not to use anything except JavaScript, css and html. No third party plugin, no jquery plugin.

Comment: Then there should be a reason in that.

Comment: Plus,web pages will go mad always if you have millions of rows.

Comment: you simply can't have that many table cells showing, you need to load in subsets on-demand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the source of this JavaScript [plugin](https://clusterize.js.org/) and take the pieces you need. The whole plugin is about 300 rows of code, you can remove some parts if you do not need them. This is a [link](https://github.com/NeXTs/Clusterize.js) to their GitHub repo.

On their demo site they append 500k rows and the scroll is smooth.

Answer (score 1):

You can not display that many DOM elements without "blocking" browser.
And there are no "optimization" techniques to handle this, the only option, as mentioned @dandavis would be to listen for scroll events and display subsets on-demand for current scroll position.

As said @Veselin [Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/) does exactly that, but it works vertically only. If you need to apply this technique for two directions (horizontally + vertically) - take a look at library called [Fattable](https://github.com/fulmicoton/fattable). [Demo](http://fulmicoton.com/fattable/index2.html)